# How to SELECT / get all rows with node-sqlite3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-sqlite3

I am trying to get all / more than one row of data out of sqlite3 database that I previously entered and ensured that it(data) is present. With `db` as the database object, my attempt looks like this:

```
 db.get
    (
        'SELECT * FROM my_table',
        (err, rows) =>
        {
            if(rows && err === null)
            {
                console.log(rows);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Error', err);
            }
        }
    )
```

Above always returns a single object with 1 row of data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue here is that `db.get()` will only return the first row from the result set.  From the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API):

> Runs the SQL query with the specified parameters and calls the callback with the first result row afterwards.

If you want to return the entire result set, use `db.all()` instead:

```
db.all("SELECT * FROM my_table", function(err, rows) {  
    rows.forEach(function (row) {  
        console.log(row.col1, row.col2);    // and other columns, if desired
    })  
});
```

You could also use `db.each()` here:

```
db.each("SELECT * FROM my_table", function(err, row) {
    console.log(row.col1, row.col2);    // and other columns, if desired
});
```

Comment: Thanks! db.all does the work, I should have paid more attention to the doc.